# Node.js: a variable in memory compared to redis (or other in-memory key/value store)

Tags: node.js, redis, memcached

I'd like to store some info. in a node.js array variable (to be a local cache) that my middleware would check before making a database query.

I know that I can do this w/redis and it's generally the preferred method b/c redis offers snapshots for persistence and is quite performant, but I can't imagine anything being more performant than a variable stored in-memory.

Every time someone brings up this topic, however, folks say "memory leaks" make this a bad idea. But why? Why is node.js bad at managing server-side vars?

Is there a preferred method (outside of an external k/v db store) of managing a server-side array/cache through node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using a node variable as storage is that by using it you have made your application unable to scale. Consider a large application which serves thousands of requests per second, and cannot be run on a single machine. If you spin up a second node process, it has different values for your node storage variable.

Let's say a user making an API call to your application hits machine 1, and stores a session variable. They make a second API call and this time are routed by your load balancer to machine 2. Their session variable is not found and you throw an error.

If you are writing a small application and have no expectations of scaling up in the near term, by all means use a node variable - I've done this myself before for auth tokens on small websites. You can always switch to redis later if you need to. Of course, you need to be aware that if your node process restarts, the contents of your variable will be lost.

Comment: Okay, great to hear! I was worried that I was overlooking something. Since I'm using the var. only for a cache, I think this is a great solution ...

Comment: Yes, cache is another great example! Go for it.